# How to do stress testing for AWS CPUUtiliazation and MemoryUtilization?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS cloud ECS services and created once ECS cluster. In which there is one FargateService and behind that 2 containers are running.
Two alarms have been created for fargate service on threashold 95.

Everything looks fine now Testing part comes into picture. I want test alarms functionality.
is there any easy way in AWS using some AWS service or manual script so that I can increase CPU and Memory use to test alarm functionality .

Comment: Yes, use alarm set state - https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/set-alarm-state.html

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks for reply, but I want to test metric data collection and if there is rule violation then alarm should trigger or its state should changed.